# Overriden virtual method still calls function in base class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have the following simple inheritance example in C++.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

class Animal{
    public:
    string mName;

    Animal(string pName){
        mName=pName;
    }

    virtual void printAnimal(){
        cout<<"Animal "<<this->mName<<endl;
    }

};

class Dog: public Animal{

    public: 
    Dog(string pName): Animal(pName){}

    void printAnimal(){
        cout<<"Dog "<<this->mName<<endl;
    }
};

class Cat: public Animal{
    public:

    Cat(string pName): Animal(pName){}


    void printAnimal(){
        cout<<"Cat "<<this->mName<<endl;
    }
};

Animal getCat(){
    return Cat("Tom");
}

Animal getDog(){
    return Dog("Scooby");
}

int main(){
    getCat().printAnimal();
    getDog().printAnimal();
}
```

To my understanding, if we override a virtual function given in the base class, then no matter whether the reference is to the base class or the derived class, when the overridden function is called, it should call the function defined in the derived class and not the base class.

So one would expect the output of the above program to be,

```
Cat Tom
Dog Scooby
```

But I get,

```
Animal Tom
Animal Scooby
```

Why is this happening? What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Read about [object slicing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing). For polymorphism to work you need to use pointers or references. I suggest you look into [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Comment: Thanks! So is unique_ptr the standard way to go in these kinds of situations?

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but why is `mName` public?

Comment: No particular reason! I just whipped up this example to demonstrate my problem.

Comment: Smart pointers is *one* way to go, and will in this simple case work very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the shared_ptr instead, to prevent object from *object slicing* as mentioned by @dude: [Demo](http://ideone.com/O2dgHe)

```
shared_ptr<Animal> getCat(){
    return make_shared<Cat>("Tom");
}

shared_ptr<Animal> getDog(){
    return make_shared<Dog>("Scooby");
}

int main(){
    getCat()->printAnimal();
    getDog()->printAnimal();
}
```

**Edit**: changed return value from pointer to shared_ptr to prevent memory leak, as correctly suggested in comments.

Comment: Wouldn't I have to worry about deleting these to avoid memory leaks then?

Comment: That way the object will leak. Use a smart pointer instead.

Comment: Thanks. Code modified.